# Preprocessing during a Kfold cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

I have noticed from various sites online that preprocessing and feature selection when dealing with Kfold Cross Validation suggest that the preprocessing and feature selection should be done on the independent folds. Is there a link that someone can suggest that I can learn on how to do this?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html

Comment: Thanks let me check this out.